# безопасный код С++. Учет длины передаваемого массива.

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

как сделать данный код безопасным в отношении длины массива символов, передаваемого через указатель?

```
void GetText(char* text)  
{      
 char exampleText[50] = "Test text";  
 strcpy_s(text, exampleText);  
}
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не использовать std::string, передаваемый по ссылке? Или просто возвращаемый из функции?

Answer (score 3):

Данный код — никак.

Если вы пользуетесь C-строками, вы не знаете, сколько памяти реально аллоцировано. Вы должны передавать дополнительный параметр, который будет указывать длину вашей памяти.

```
bool GetText(char* text, size_t size)
{
    const size_t length = 50;
    if (size > length)
        return false;
    char exampleText[length] = "Test text";
    strcpy_s(text, exampleText);
    return true;
}
```

Если вы работаете с C++, то имеет смысл переключиться на конструкции более в духе языка. Например, вы можете превратить вашу функцию в шаблон, и использовать `std::array`:

```
template<size_t size>
bool GetText(std::array<char, size>& text)
{
    const size_t length = 50;
    if (size < length)
        return false;
    char exampleText[length] = "Test text";
    strcpy_s(text.data(), size, exampleText);
    return true;
}
```

Или если длина буфера динамическая, то (как советовал в комментариях @Voidificator) просто перейдите на `std::string`:

```
void GetText(std::string& text)
{
    text = "Test text";
}
```

или ещё лучше

```
std::string GetText()
{
    return "Test text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам поможет что-то такое:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N>
void foo(const T (&arr)[N])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "some string";
    int ints[] = { 1, 3, 7, 11 };
    foo(str);
    foo(ints);
}
```

Но это только для встроенных массивов, не для указателей на массивы.
А так, рекомендую прислушаться к @Voidificator и использовать std::string.